# Changing Android Shared Preference Value from String to Int

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm updating my Android app. The app retrieves data from my server and among that data is a user id. The user id is a number (Integer) but it arrives from the server as a string eg "1234". In the old version I then saved this user id as a string in my shared prefernces but now that I'm looking back at it I don't like this and want to save it as an Integer as it should be.

So far pretty simple. I just use putInt / getInt rather than putString / getString. The problem is that all the people currently using the app will have the value saved in their shared preferences as a string and then when they update the app the new version of the app will start to try to use getInt to get the value which the old version saved as a string.

What's the best way to avoid any errors because of this and ensure a smoothe transition between the two app versions?

Thanks.

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd add a snippet of code in a custom `Application` `onCreate()` that tries reading in the int. If that fails, try reading in the string. If that succeeds, convert it into the corresponding int and save it. That way, by the time your "regular" app code gets control, things should be converted. That being said, personally, I'd leave it as a string, in case you decide to go alphanumeric on the user ID in the future.

Comment: At any rate, I would not change the type of a `Preferences` item. If you want to change to `int`, create a new entry and check them both. I usually create a wrapper around `SharedPreferences` so this type of changes don't affect my code.

Comment: Yep, I'm going to go with the @CommonsWare. The user id that the server provides is an Int in my mySQL database so its not going to become alphanumeric any time soon. I've accepted answer below from Prexx as it provides an example that may be useful for others later on. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that in your onCreate:

```
try{
   prefs.getInt("key", 0);
}catch (ClassCastException e){
   Integer uid = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("key", null);
   if(uid != null)
      prefs.edit().putInt("key", uid).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This is what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as

```
int userid = Integer.parseInt( preferences.getString("userid", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert you string user id into integer like,

```
int uid=Integer.parseInt("1234");//here is your string user id in place of 1234.
```

and then write uid into your shared preference with putExtra(key,intValue).

that's it.